# How can I send myself an email that becomes a text file on my hard drive (or on Dropbox)?

Tags: text-editing, evernote, note-taking

Evernote has a very helpful feature that lets me send an email to a special address and which makes that email into a new note.

I'd like to duplicate that functionality, but without being locked into Evernote.

Do you know how I could do that?

Basically, I'd like whatever I send to a special email address to be converted into a note on my hard drive.

Comment: What operating system? What kind of email software are you using? What kinds of email accounts do you have access to? Do you have access to a mail server? Do you intend to be not locked in to *any* software (sounds impossible here)? It probably would help to know why you want to do this rather than just use a text editor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.dropbox.com/apps/833/send-to-dropbox might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it with some complex scripting, but it would not only take a lot of effort to achieve, I imagine it would not be very robust.

After trying to imagine why you'd want something like that, I'd remind you that Evernote has versions that run on smartphones.

There is also Microsoft OneNote (which I prefer), which syncs on the web, and there is a OneNote web app, so you can edit your web notebooks from any internet connected computer.  The OneNote mobile program for the new Windows Phone 7 OS looks very good as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind some programming you could use perl or something and an IMAP or pop3 module to check an email address on an interval and then write new messages to a folder.