# How can I e-mail files to dropbox?

Tags: email, dropbox

I'd like to be able to send an e-mail and have the attachments (and possibly the body of the e-mail) uploaded into my dropbox. I saw [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/199977/how-can-i-send-myself-an-email-that-becomes-a-text-file-on-my-hard-drive-or-on), which has one "correct" answer which is a broken link.

Does anybody know a way to e-mail files into your dropbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the moment this feature is not available in dropbox.

you can vote for it here:

- https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/20/email-files-to-dropbox

note: you have to sign in to be able to vote...

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox used to have the ability to run addons, but it seems they silently removed that feature and section of their website one day. It looks like we're now relegated to submitting and voting on feature requests, such as the one @udo shared.